# What is the best way to map Caps Lock to windows key permanently?

Tags: ubuntu, x11, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I have this right now in my ~/.Xmodmap

```
clear Lock
keycode 66 = Hyper_L
```

and `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` in ~/.bashrc.

This works alright for the first time but randomly the Caps Lock key goes back to working as a Caps Lock and I have to run the xmodmap command(generally by opening a terminal there by running ~/.bashrc) to map it back to windows key.

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and using i3 window manager.

Is there a more robust way to do the mapping?

Comment: Don't call `xmodmap` from `.bashrc`: that triggers when you open a terminal, not when you log in. Put it in `.profile`, or use the GUI settings.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Keyboard layout options]

You can go into system settings -> Keyboard -> Layout -> Options and configure it there. It does not require writing any scripts or running any programs at login. Just configure once and enjoy.

PS: This have been tried on Linux Mint 15 Cinnamon, Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon, Linux Mint 16 XFCE, Fedora 24 GNOME and Manjaro KDE. I'm sure Ubuntu 14.04 would also have similar option to configure.

Comment: I couldn't find a similar way to configure using system settings from unity-control-center. The keyboard settings don't this kind of configuration options.

Comment: @ma08 I think you need to use the Gnome control center. The Unity control center is even more of a joke.